# Is there a way to customize the Contact Dashboard?

Tags: user-dashboard

Is there a way to customize the Contact Dashboard?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Civi has a couple different dashboards. Can you edit your question to say *which* dashboard you are talking about and what exactly you'd like to do with it? That will help people give you the answers you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was referring to the end user forms such as the Use dashboard; profile; contribution page and event page. How can I create a custom page for a end user to view online?
Thank you again. Sincerely,
Chaim Glassman

Comment: Please *edit* your question instead of creating an answer or a comment or a new question. It's still not  clear exactly what you want to do. Modify how? Create a custom page to do what? What is your goal? What documentation have you read so far, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please add these details to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Laryn covers basic customization of the main dashboard (assuming that's the dashboard you're referring to).  You can also customize further:

- If you're running Drupal, [Views in Dashlets](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_views_dashlets) is a great way to get highly-customized dashlets with no coding.
- If you ARE looking for coding suggestions, [hook_civicrm_dashboard](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_dashboard) is the place to look.  Also check out [hook_civicrm_dashboard_defaults](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_dashboard_defaults) to handle setting the default dashlets for your users.

Answer (score 1):

For a fuller description including how to create dashlets, [see the chapter/documentation about the Dashboard here](http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/the-user-interface/menu-dashboard-and-dashlets/). (Excerpts below).

> When you first log into CiviCRM, the first page that you will see is the dashboard (CiviCRM Home). The dashboard allows you to see important information about your site and CiviCRM by displaying a series of "dashlets". A dashlet is a report that you can display on your home dashboard. Many dashlets come with CiviCRM by default, and you or your administrator can create additional dashlets that are specific to your organization's needs...
>
> You can add these dashlets to your CiviCRM dashboard by clicking the Configure Your Dashboard button. You will see a list of dashlets that can be dragged into the right or left column of your dashboard.